# Mass update values from the rown in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How can i update all the fields from a  certain row within Mysql database .
By DB is : `bookinga_Hotels`
The Tabele is : `HotelList`
The column with the value that i need to update  is : `HotelImages`
And i want to update all the rows where `"image.metglobal.com"` with `"bookingassist.ro"`

Have any ideea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as

```
update HotelList
set HotelImages = 'bookingassist.ro'
where HotelImages = 'image.metglobal.com'
```

If you have mix of strings along with the image url then you can use `replace`

```
update HotelList
set HotelImages = replace(HotelImages,'image.metglobal.com','bookingassist.ro');
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to execute this MySQL query :

```
update HotelList 
set HotelImages = 'bookingassist.ro'
where HotelImages = 'image.metglobal.com'
```